# Why do my lights become brighter during a thunderstorm?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, lightning, weather

Today, during a thunderstorm, the lamps in the room suddenly flickered and then gradually became brighter in less than a second. The lamps remained brighter than normal for a few seconds before returning to normal. Can someone explain to me the physics behind this occurrence?

Comment: How often does this happen?

Comment: @probably_someone This was the first time it happened in probably 30 - 40 thunderstorms.

Comment: Does it ever happen outside of thunderstorms?

Comment: @probably_someone It does not.

Comment: Once again I'm amazed how some physic purists downvote every single question not related to some deep theoretical concept.

Answer (score 2):

If a bolt of lightning strikes a power line, it will blow up the nearest transformers on that line and pop all their fuses. Suddenly, a large portion of the network's load has been shed but the inductance in the network strives to maintain the original value of the current flow- generating a voltage spike in the network. So the source of the voltage surge mentioned by probably_someone is this "inductive kick" effect.

Answer (score 0):

The thunderstorm likely caused a power surge somewhere, and whatever buffers were put in place to absorb the surge were unable to completely contain it.